# vbscript embedded in page hosted in iis not executing

Tags: iis, vbscript

I inherited an old classic asp app.  I am trying to get it to run locally on iis on windows xp.  I am having trouble getting the vbscript pieces to execute.
I then went and created a simple vbscript hello world page and it still is not executing and rendering as expected.

Does anyone know if there is an iis setting that will not allow vbscript to execute?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - it actually ended up being a browser issue.  It was a combination of using an incorrect version of one browser coupled with some default internal settings on another browser.

sorry for any confusion.